# Why does locale es_MX work but not es?

Tags: c++, linux, internationalization, gettext

[Wikipedia entry for GNU gettext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Msgfmt#Programming) shows an example where the locale is just the lanuage, "fr". Whereas the [i18n gettext() “hello world” example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003360/complete-c-i18n-gettext-hello-world-example/1033337#1033337) has the locale value with both the language and country, "`es_MX`". I have modified the "`es_MX`" example to use just the lanuage, "es", but it produces the English text rather the expected Spanish.

```
cat >hellogt.cxx <<EOF
// hellogt.cxx
#include <libintl.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <iostream>
int main (){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    bindtextdomain("hellogt", ".");
    textdomain( "hellogt");
    std::cout << gettext("hello, world!") << std::endl;
}
EOF
g++ -o hellogt hellogt.cxx
xgettext --package-name hellogt --package-version 1.2 --default-domain hellogt --output hellogt.pot hellogt.cxx
msginit --no-translator --locale es --output-file hellogt_spanish.po --input hellogt.pot
sed --in-place hellogt_spanish.po --expression='/"hello, world!"/,/#: / s/""/"hola mundo"/'
mkdir --parents ./es.utf8/LC_MESSAGES
msgfmt --check --verbose --output-file ./es.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/hellogt.mo hellogt_spanish.po
LANG=es.utf8 ./hellogt
```

According to [Controlling your locale with environment variables](http://www.linux.com/archive/feature/53781):

> environment variable, LANGUAGE, which
>   is used only by GNU gettext ... If
>   defined, LANGUAGE takes precedence
>   over LC_ALL, LC_MESSAGES, and LANG.

```
LANGUAGE=es.utf8 ./hellogt
```

produces the expected Spanish text rather than English.

But this does not explain why "LANG=es" does not work.

Answer (score 3):

Hmmm... it sounds like a platform problem. I did precisely the same thing under Mac OSX and got the expected results. I suspect that your version of linux doesn't like `LANG=es.utf8`. Check your local system documentation surrounding things like `setlocale(3)` or `xlocale(3)` if the latter is even supported.

IIRC, locale identifiers containing only a primary identifier which was an ISO-639 language code had the ISO-3166 country code of the primary speaking country appended to them. Then the resulting locale lookup was performed by looking in `/usr/share/locale`. I looked in the locale directory on my MacBook and there is a directory named `es` as well as `es_ES`. It may be a simple system configuration issue.

I would highly recommend using [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) instead of gettext and the locale stuff offered by the Standard Library if you are developing a commercial application. Gettext will work for simple message lookup but it doesn't offer nearly what you need to really do a fully internationalized application.