# Command or option for the xgettext, msginit, msgfmt sequence for setting the MIME type?

Tags: linux, internationalization, gettext

[msgfmt “invalid multibyte sequence” error on a Polish text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083518/msgfmt-invalid-multibyte-sequence-error-on-a-polish-text) is corrected by manually editing the MIME Content-Type charset in the template file. Is there some command or option for the xgettext, msginit, msgfmt sequence for setting the MIME type?

```
cat >plt.cxx <<EOF
// plt.cxx
#include <libintl.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <iostream>
int main (){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    bindtextdomain("plt", ".");
    textdomain( "plt");
    std::cout << gettext("Invalid input. Enter a string at least 20 characters long.") << std::endl;
}
EOF
g++ -o plt plt.cxx
xgettext --package-name plt --package-version 1.2 --default-domain plt --output plt.pot plt.cxx
sed --in-place plt.pot --expression='s/CHARSET/UTF-8/'
msginit --no-translator --locale pl_PL --output-file plt_polish.po --input plt.pot
sed --in-place plt_polish.po --expression='/#: /,$ s/""/"Nieprawidłowo wprowadzone dane. Wprowadź ciąg przynajmniej 20 znaków."/'
mkdir --parents ./pl_PL.utf8/LC_MESSAGES
msgfmt --check --verbose --output-file ./pl_PL.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/plt.mo plt_polish.po
LANGUAGE=pl_PL.utf8 ./plt
```

Answer (score 10):

Just give full locale name and msginit will set charset correctly

```
msginit --no-translator --input=xx.pot --locale=ru_RU.UTF-8
```

results in

```
"Language: ru\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
```

Answer (score 8):

There is no argument for setting the output character encoding directly, but this should *in pratice* not be a problem, as your PO editor will automatically use an appropriate character encoding when saving the PO file (one that supports all the characters used in the translation), and replace `CHARSET` in the file with the name of the encoding. If it doesn’t, file a bug.

The only problem would be if the POT file contained non-ASCII characters, but `xgettext` *does* have a `--from-code` argument for this, which specifies the encoding of the *input* files. If the input contains non-ASCII characters and `--from-code` is set to the correct encoding, the output POT file will have the character encoding set to UTF-8 (this need not be equal to the input character encoding). However, if the input files only contain ASCII characters, `--from-code=UTF-8` will unfortunately have no effect.

`msginit` does in fact automatically set the character encoding to something ‘appropriate’ for the chosen target locale. However, the list of locale to character encoding pairs seems outdated; UTF-8 is now really the best choice for all languages.

An alternative would be to use [`pot2po`](http://translate.sourceforge.net/wiki/toolkit/pot2po) instead of `msginit`. This always uses UTF-8 automatically, AFAICS. However, unlike `msginit`, it does not automatically fill out the plural forms of the PO file, which may or may not be a problem (some think it is the job of the PO editor to do this).