# Handling plurals using xgettextt with --extract-all

Tags: c++, linux, internationalization, xgettext

Using `--extract-all` with `xgettext` does not work with plurals. Using the answer to [I18n C++ hello world with plurals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108203/i18n-c-hello-world-with-plurals) as the C++ code here are two tests using `xgettext`.

```
cat >helloplurals.cxx <<EOF
// hellopurals.cxx
#include <libintl.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <iostream>
int main (){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    bindtextdomain("helloplurals", ".");
    textdomain( "helloplurals");
    for (int ii=0; ii<5; ii++)
        printf(ngettext("Hello world with %d moon.\n", "Hello world with %d moons.\n", ii), ii);
EOF
xgettext --package-name helloplurals --package-version 1.1 --default-domain helloplurals --output helloplurals.pot helloplurals.cxx
xgettext --extract-all --package-name helloplurals --package-version 1.1 --default-domain helloplurals --output helloplurals-ea.pot helloplurals.cxx
```

The one without `--extract-all` works as expected including the handling of plurals:

```
#: helloplurals.cxx:10
#, c-format
msgid "Hello world with %d moon.\n"
msgid_plural "Hello world with %d moons.\n"
msgstr[0] ""
msgstr[1] ""
```

When `--extract-all` is added to the command line the resulting POT file does not. Instead there are separate entries:

```
#: helloplurals.cxx:10
#, c-format
msgid "Hello world with %d moon.\n"
msgstr ""

#: helloplurals.cxx:10
#, c-format
msgid "Hello world with %d moons.\n"
msgstr ""
```

String literals that are passed directly to the `gettext()` like functions properly handle plural messages as shown in the first example use of `xgettext`.

For string literals that are not passed directly to one of the `gettext()` like functions
the use of the option `--extract-all` with `xgettext` can be used to produce the entries in a POT file.

How does one get the handling of string literals that are not passed directly to the `gettext()` like functions in source that also contains plural string literals that are passed directly to `gettext()` like function to produce the plural entries: `msgid_plural`  and `msgstr[]`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think xgettext supports that. If you pass --extract-all, it will ignore any context where a string occurs. You may consider reporting this as bug.

I would recommend to mark up all strings explicitly, anyway. There is good tool support to do that fairly quickly.