# How to initialize a static char* with gettetxt() using local operating system environment?

Tags: c++, linux, internationalization, gettext

Is there a standard or common way in C++ to handle static strings that need to be set by `gettext()`?

Here is an example using the answer to [Complete C++ i18n gettext() “hello world” example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003360/complete-c-i18n-gettext-hello-world-example/1033337#1033337) as a base just changing the literal `hello world` to a static `char* hws` and `char* hw`.
It looks like `hws` is getting initialized to the default English text before the locale is set from the
local operating system environment. While `hw` is getting set after the locale is changed thus producing the Spanish text.

```
cat >hellostaticgt.cxx <<EOF
// hellostaticgt.cxx
#include <libintl.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <iostream>
char* hws = gettext("hello, world static!");
int main (){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    bindtextdomain("hellostaticgt", ".");
    textdomain( "hellostaticgt");
    char* hw = gettext("hello, world!");
    std::cout << hws << std::endl;
    std::cout << hw << std::endl;
}
EOF
g++ -o hellostaticgt hellostaticgt.cxx
xgettext --package-name hellostaticgt --package-version 1.0 --default-domain hellostaticgt --output hellostaticgt.pot hellostaticgt.cxx
msginit --no-translator --locale es_MX --output-file hellostaticgt_spanish.po --input hellostaticgt.pot
sed --in-place hellostaticgt_spanish.po --expression='/#: /,$ s/""/"hola mundo"/'
mkdir --parents ./es_MX.utf8/LC_MESSAGES
msgfmt --check --verbose --output-file ./es_MX.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/hellostaticgt.mo hellostaticgt_spanish.po
LANGUAGE=es_MX.utf8 ./hellostaticgt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split gettext usage into two parts. First, you just mark the string with a macro, such as gettext_noop, so that xgettext will extract it. Then, when you refer to the the global variable, you wrap the access with the true gettext call.

See [Special Cases](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Special-cases.html) in the gettext manual.

N.B. Your variable hws is not a static variable (no "static keyword"); it is a global variable.

Comment: Changed formatting of "static" in "static char* hws". B.Stroustrup, The C++ Programming Language Third Edition, pg 83 states that global, namespace and local static objects are collectively called static objects.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code after applying the [answer from Martin v. Löwis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114792/how-to-initialization-a-static-char-with-gettetxt-using-local-operating-system/1115340#1115340):

```
cat >hellostaticgt.cxx <<EOF
// hellostaticgt.cxx
#include <libintl.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <iostream>
#define gettext_noop(S) S
const char* hws_eng = gettext_noop("hello, world static!");
int main (){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    bindtextdomain("hellostaticgt", ".");
    textdomain( "hellostaticgt");
    char* hw = gettext("hello, world!");
    std::cout << gettext(hws_eng) << std::endl;
    std::cout << hw << std::endl;
}
EOF
g++ -o hellostaticgt hellostaticgt.cxx
xgettext --package-name hellostaticgt --package-version 1.0 --default-domain hellostaticgt --output hellostaticgt.pot hellostaticgt.cxx
msginit --no-translator --locale es_MX --output-file hellostaticgt_spanish.po --input hellostaticgt.pot
sed --in-place hellostaticgt_spanish.po --expression='/"hello, world static!"/,/#: / s/""/"hola mundo static"/'
sed --in-place hellostaticgt_spanish.po --expression='/"hello, world!"/,/#: / s/""/"hola mundo"/'
mkdir --parents ./es_MX.utf8/LC_MESSAGES
msgfmt --check --verbose --output-file ./es_MX.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/hellostaticgt.mo hellostaticgt_spanish.po
LANGUAGE=es_MX.utf8 ./hellostaticgt
```

The result has the desired and expected output:

```
hola mundo static
hola mundo
```