# How to trace the C++ GNU xgettex execution?

Tags: c++, internationalization, gettext

Hi I am writing a sample code for i18n in c++. I referenced the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003360/complete-c-i18n-gettext-hello-world-example).

The output displays the text in english. What is the problem here?

```
 #include "start.hpp"
 #include <iostream>
 #include <locale.h>
 #include "/opt/local/share/gettext/gettext.h"
 using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

char* cwd = getenv("PWD");
std::cout << "getenv(PWD): " << (cwd?cwd:"NULL") << std::endl;
char* l = getenv("LANG");
std::cout << "getenv(LANG): " << (l?l:"NULL") << std::endl;
char* s = setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
std::cout << "setlocale(): " << (s?s:"NULL") << std::endl;
std::cout << "bindtextdomain(): " << bindtextdomain("hello", cwd) <<         std::endl;
std::cout << "textdomain(): " << textdomain( "hello") << std::endl;
std::cout << gettext("hello, world!") << std::endl;

return 0;
```

}

> $> g++ -o start start.cpp
>
> $> xgettext -d start -o start.pot start.cpp
>
> $> msginit  --no-translator -l es_MX -o start_es.po -i start.pot
>
> Created start_es.po.

I opened the start_es.po files using poedit.app and translated the text and saved

> $> mkdir -p es/LC_MESSAGES
>
> $> msgfmt -c -v -o ./es/LC_MESSAGES/start.mo start_es.po
>
> 1 translated message.
>
> $>export LANG=es_MX
>
> $> ./start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in the code while binding domains. I changed that as follows

```
std::cout << "setlocale(): " << (s ? s : "NULL") << std::endl;
std::cout << "bindtextdomain(): " << bindtextdomain(“start", cwd)<< std::endl;
std::cout << "textdomain(): " << textdomain( “start") << std::endl;
```

The following trace helped me to find that out.

```
 dhcp-140:Debug UserName $ sudo dtruss -f -t open ./start
getenv(PWD): /Users/UserName/WorkPlace/lang/DerivedData/lang/Build/Products/Debug
getenv(LANG): NULL
setlocale(): NULL
bindtextdomain(): 

/Users/UserName/WorkPlace/lang/DerivedData/lang/Build/Products/Debug
textdomain(): hello
hello, world!
    PID/THRD  SYSCALL(args)          = return
 7213/0x16cd1:  open(".\0", 0x0, 0x1)        = 3 0
 7213/0x16cd1:  open("/usr/lib/dtrace/libdtrace_dyld.dylib\0", 0x0, 0x0)     = 3 0
 7213/0x16cd1:  open("/opt/local/lib/libintl.8.dylib\0", 0x0, 0x0)       = 3 0
 7213/0x16cd1:  open("/opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib\0", 0x0, 0x0)      = 3 0
 7213/0x16cd1:  open("/dev/dtracehelper\0", 0x2, 0x7FFF540FDA20)         = 3 0
 7213/0x16cd1:  open("/Users/UserName/WorkPlace/lang/DerivedData/lang/Build/Products/Debug/./start\0", 0x0, 0x1FF)       = 3 0
 7213/0x16cd1:  open("/Users/UserName/WorkPlace/lang/DerivedData/lang/Build/Products/Debug/en/LC_MESSAGES/hello.mo\0", 0x0, 0x8)         = -1 Err#2
```